# Push Notification with out active google account in android

Tags: android

We have a scenario where we don't want the user to register to google account to send the notifications in android platform.But as per stackmob documentation we found that we need to register the With google to send notifications. So kindly guide us how to send notifications with out GCM ?

Thanks& Regards, 
Sai Sravan.P

Answer (score 1):

every Android user with a device that runs 2.2 and above must have a google account (the device has the google play app).

there for I'm not really sure why you fear this scenario...

Answer (score 0):

I guess for GCM you need a Google Account so you can use xmpp instead GCM and every android device user must have a Google Account.